# 'DRY'ing up my Ruby Syntax

Tags: ruby, dry

I have a repeated comparison in which I have to check whether three variables equal a certain variable.  For simplicity, I'll create a scenario that illustrates the problem that I am having.

```
if time == -1 and day_of_week == -1 and month == -1
```

I was wondering if there is a terse, logically-equivalent way of achieving this same line of code without the repetition.

Right now I'm using a roundabout way of doing this as follows:

```
all_equal = true
[time_now, day_of_week, month].each { |value| all_equal = false if value != -1 }
if all_equal ....
```

Hah, obviously it's pretty over the top (and clearly less efficient) but I find the lack of repetition more pleasing to look at.

Would you recommend a better approach to this?

Thank you!

Comment: aside from being less readable, your second version is inferior because it does not allow short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
if [time_now, day_of_week, month].all? { |value| value == -1 }
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Create thanks.  Was looking for an 'all' method of some sort earlier but I guess I looked over this!

Comment: The thing is, a lot of methods you could use to operate on arrays also work on other enumerable types, so I always make sure to take a *good* look in the `Enumerable` docs just in case. That module provides a LOT of cool functionality on any type that defines an `#each` method. It's pretty awesome!

Comment: It's surprising that I've been using ruby for so long but haven't really taken the time to learn all the interesting quirks about it like Enumerable.  Thanks again!